# Add rows to insert dates from a "from" and "to" column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, date

I want to breakdown an Excel sheet by having it in a specific format.
Right now, the sheet is like this

```
FROM           TO     TOTAL
01/27/12    01/27/12    1
03/09/12    03/09/12    1
04/11/12    04/13/12    3
12/24/12    01/04/13    7
06/04/12    06/13/12    8
```

I want to have Excel break down the dates on a row by row basis excluding Saturdays and Sundays. 
Example: 04/11/12 to 04/13/12. 3 days total should become

```
04/11/12
04/12/12
04/13/12
```

Any means of how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you imported the data with space as the delimiter?

Comment: To help improve your question, can you tell us what you have tried?

Comment: Your `12/24/12 -> 01/04/13 = 7` example works only if you exclude holidays as well as weekends.  That probably makes the question harder.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly manual process would be to insert the number of rows you want. Then select the starting date and swipe down and highlight those new rows. Using the `Fill -> Series` dialog (in the `Editing` panel on the `Home` tab) you can fill in the dates with Sat and Sun skipped (just select `Date` and `Weekday`)

[image: series]

Comment: You can get a pop-up menu that gives you similar capabilities if you “swipe”/drag with the right mouse button.